# Explain why FXML objects were null

Tags: java, javafx

I came across a problem in my code that all the objects that were related to the FXML file for a controller class were null even though the styling from the FXML was working and all the fx:id tags were the same. Here is the FXML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>

<VBox xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx"
      xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
      alignment="center"
      spacing="10"
      prefHeight="750"
      prefWidth="1000"
      style="-fx-background-color: lightslategray">
    <padding><Insets top="0" bottom="10" left="10" right="10"></Insets></padding> <!-- Set the padding at 10px for each side of the window -->
    <Label fx:id="titleLabel" style="-fx-font-weight: bold; -fx-font-size: 32;" wrapText="true" text="Deck Title"/>
    <HBox spacing="10">
        <Button fx:id="backButton" text="Back" prefWidth="50"/>
        <ProgressBar fx:id="progressIndicator" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="0" prefWidth="920" progress="0.0"/>
    </HBox>
    <HBox spacing="20">
        <Label fx:id="qLabel" style="-fx-background-color: white; -fx-border-color: black" prefWidth="480" prefHeight="400" wrapText="true"/>
        <Label fx:id="aLabel" style="-fx-background-color: white; -fx-border-color: black; -fx-cursor: hand" prefWidth="480" prefHeight="400" wrapText="true" text="Click here to reveal the answer" onMouseClicked="#updateAnswer"/>
    </HBox>
    <HBox spacing="780">
        <Button fx:id="incorrectButton" text="Incorrect" prefWidth="100"/>
        <Button fx:id="correctButton" text="Correct" prefWidth="100"/>
    </HBox>
</VBox>
```

Here is the code for the controller class:

```
public class openCardsController {

@FXML Button backButton;
@FXML ProgressBar progressIndicator;
@FXML Label qLabel;
@FXML Label aLabel;
@FXML Label titleLabel;
@FXML Button incorrectButton;
@FXML Button correctButton;

public void openCards() throws IOException, ParseException {
    Stage window = Main.getStage();
    window.setWidth(1000);
    window.setHeight(750);

    // Had to swap Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("./mainPage.fxml")); for the following lines
    File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/flashcardApplication/openCardsPage.fxml");
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(file.toURI().toURL());
    loader.setController(this);


    VBox root = loader.load();
    backButton.setOnAction(e -> {
        try {
            backButtonPressed();
        } catch (IOException ignored) {}
    });
    incorrectButton.setOnAction(e -> incorrect());
    correctButton.setOnAction(e -> correct());
    window.setTitle("Flashcard Application - Open Cards");
    Scene mainMenuScene = new Scene(root, 1000, 750);
    window.setScene(mainMenuScene);
    int deckid = chooseCards();
    String fileURL = "ftp://appuser:pass123.@127.0.0.1/decks/" + Integer.toString(deckid) + ".json";
    URL url = new URL(fileURL); // Lines 43 to 45 come from https://www.javaworld.com/article/2073325/java-ftp-client-libraries-reviewed.html
    URLConnection urlc = url.openConnection();
    InputStream inputStream = urlc.getInputStream();
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject)jsonParser.parse(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));
    String title = (String) jsonObject.get("name");
    titleLabel.setText(title);
}
```

I had to remove the attribute `fx:controller="flashcardApplication.openCardsController` from the FXML file and I had to replace the line `Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("./mainPage.fxml"));` with the following lines:

```
File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/flashcardApplication/openCardsPage.fxml");
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(file.toURI().toURL());
loader.setController(this);
```

Please could someone explain why I had to use the different solution because I used the one line solution in two other FXML files and their corresponding controller classes without any issues

Comment: Off-topic: don't use a `File` to specify the location of the FXML. This will break if (when) you bundle the application as a jar file. (And regardless, you certainly should not be loading from the *source* folder.) Use a resource: `URL fxml = getClass().getResource("openCardsPage.fxml");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `@FXML`-annotated fields are initialized in the controller when the FXML is loaded. By default, the `FXMLLoader` creates an instance of the class specified by the `fx:controller` attribute, and uses it as the controller.

Consequently, in your original code, the controller is not the current instance of `OpenCardsController` on which `openCards()` is being invoked, but is the new instance of the same class. Thus the `@FXML`-annotated fields are not initialized in the current instance, but in the new instance that is created by the `FXMLLoader`.

By removing the `fx:controller` attribute, and explicitly setting the controller to the exact object you need (the current instance of `OpenCardsController`), you achieve what you need: the controller is now the current instance and the `FXML`-annotated fields are initialized in that object.

Note that it's a bit unusual to load the FXML file from the controller itself. The typical approach is to load the FXML from some other code, and display the resulting UI; the controller is usually a separate object. It may be more natural (and easier to maintain in the long run) if you refactor your code so that the FXML is loaded from somewhere else. (This is really a separation of concerns and single-responsibility issue: the controller should only be responsible for processing user input from the corresponding FXML file; it should not be responsible for loading the FXML as well.)